# How do i add < condition in excel 2010

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010

Hello I have data in pivot tables that tells me what area am i under penetrated,but i want to add condition something to pivot table and then able to change the numbers .Ex
show me the data for < 20% penetration.all the formulas is done by IT in pivot , i just need to be able to add = < 20% or > 20 % condition to suit my needs. I am a newby to excel so please help me understand as simple as possible. 
ty
Meh
Penetration
49.4%
46.6%
51.5%
43.2%
42.0%
49.7%
33.1%
19.8%
28.2%
32.6%
56.4%
48.5%

Answer (score 0):

I have next to no idea what you want but maybe this would be a start towards finding out:

[image: SO21260441 example]